# Haskell Construction of List from Tuple List

Tags: haskell

I have a list of tuples where each tuple represents the row and column of a pixel. How would I go about efficiently constructing a list where for each `(i, j)` tuple in the first list, the element at the `i*width + j` position in the new list has a value of 1?

Comment: Efficient as opposed to what approach? Surely you can do this _somehow_.

Comment: If you're talking pixels, don't you mean `i+stride*j` position, instead of `i*j`?  Or, do you actually want to conflate all tuples whose elements multiply to give the same value?

Comment: I tried to check for every combination of i and j if the tuple (i, j) was an element of the first list, but that approach seemed to be too slow.

Comment: I'm trying to see which pixels need to be rendered so I want pixels with the same `i` and `j` values to give the same value.

Comment: pixel (3,2) is different from pixels (2,3), (1,6), (6,1)... However you are looking for a map function.. It should not be hard.

Comment: I need to construct a list of color values for each pixel so that I can render with the glDrawPIxels function from opengl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, sort the list of points

```
let sortedPoints = sort [(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
-- == [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0)]
```

Then, create the list of all points

```
let allPoints = [(x, y) | x <- [0, 3], y <- [0, 3]]
-- where I chose width = 3
-- = [(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,0),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)]
```

Note that this comes automatically sorted.

Finally, write a function that goes through the items one by one and checks which items from list sortedPoints are in allPoints

```
isIn::[(Int, Int)]->[(Int, Int)]->[Int]
isIn [] [] = []
isIn (first:rest) (allFirst:allRest) | first == allFirst = 1:isIn rest allRest
isIn points (_:rest) = 0:isIn points rest
```

Then just calculate

```
isIn sortedPoints allPoints
```